# DBT JINJA IF ELSE

Tags: jinja2, dbt

im pretty new to DBT and Jinja, in my DBT project i want to do a simple control structure using an if block but i dont get why the evaluation of the block is so messed up.

```
SELECT *,
{% if a == 'B2B' and b != 'GERMANY' %}
Do something if
{% else %}
Do something else
{% endif %}
FROM ref('table')
```

a and b are columns of table but they dont get correctly evaluated. I want to do declare some columns with a value when the if statement is true and some other values if it fails. What am i missing?

I know its possible to do with CASE WHEN in SQL but i dont want to have multiple CASE statements that do the same thing. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

dbt evaluates jinja at compile time, not run-time, and as such the jinja code you're writing doesn't have access to the data in your warehouse, so this method won't work.

A few candidate options:

1. Create a dbt macro that includes your case statement and use that in multiple places.
2. If your case statement can be represented that way, consider creating a mapping seed and then joining to it.